# How to create a web page in Android?

Tags: android, forms, webforms, html, android-webview

I want my activity to link to a web page which I have created.

I want to create the web page contents in Android.

How is it possible?

Comment: What is the web page content? Is it in a String? Or an html file? Or on the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little unclear what your requirements are... But it sounds like [WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) is probably what you are looking for.
It allows you to include web pages inside of your app. i.e. linking to a web from within a view, and stay within an app.  This also allows you to potentially "create" content inside of an activity, save it to the file system and load it through your WebView.  Otherwise, if you want to "create" content you can use your own homegrown web services to send content to a remote server to then accessed by your webview, or through the regular browser.
If you are just trying to open a link from your app in the standard browser try looking using intents.  See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c205b975a4861694) for an example.